# Appeal "For / Of " refund request?

Tags: prepositions

We received a refund request from an insurance company. Now I have to send an appeal.
So, what is the correct way of typing the subject?
is it,

1. Appeal of Refund request.
2. Appeal for Refund request.

Comment: I would favor *of* there, but if you're in doubt get rid of the preposition altogether and rearrange the wording: *Refund Request Appeal*. In any case, the insurance company will know what you mean.

Comment: Or just write it out in plain language: *We are appealing the request for a refund.* Sometimes, longer can be simpler. You don't *have* to use abbreviated subjects in email messages.

Comment: To add to the above, if you did want to use the second, I'd add a word: Appeal for **a** Refund request.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the situation correctly (the third party are requesting money from yourselves), then the word you are looking for is 'against' -

Appeal against Refund Request

Part of the reason you are struggling is that 'Appeal' and 'Request' don't usually go together; Appeals are usually associated with demands for payment, whereas a true 'Request' would merely need to be 'turned down'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are appealing the refund request, you can phrase it as "Appeal of Refund Request". "For" and "against" sound odd to me (in general American English).